# How to reproduce a smartphone cover material with some specific reflection patterns

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, shaders

I am working on a smartphone render, on Blender 2.79 with Cycles, using mainly the new Principled shader. Everything is working perfectly, I am not new to 3D nor Blender, but there's a very specific surface that has proven difficult.

The back cover of the phone is made of some sort of glass (tempered glass) on top of a plastic surface (as I have come to guess, I might be wrong); and the mix gives a very particular kind of reflections.

[image]

I have managed to get close by combining Anisotropy and Clearcoat, but the result is still not satisfying. I'm even thinking about working without the Anisotropic reflections at all.

Here's a link to some pics of the real phone and some screens of what I have done so far.

[image]
[image]

I hope someone can help me with this.

Thank you

Comment: You need to make AO map for that kind of reflection

Comment: Hello Nuhan, AO like Ambient Occlusion?

Comment: yes Ambient Occlusion map or roughness map.

Comment: What's the image texture that you are using for mixing the two shaders?

Comment: That one is for the little patch on top of the cameras. There's a little rectangle zone where the material reflections stretch horizontally instead of vertically, so I made two different shaders and mixed them with a texture. The only thing that changes between them is basically the roughness and the anisotropy. I'll upload a couple of pics to help

Comment: That's clear enough! Did you recreate the scene lighting using elongated blue "gas lights"?

Comment: Ok. For lighting I used an HDRI and a rectangle with emission for global lighting; and four spheres with emission just to recreate the reflections. As I have seen on the real phone, those "beams" only appear when the phone is facing a light source.

Answer (score 1):

This is really just a supplement to Nicola's answer: my approach was to control the Anisotropic Rotation with a grad something like this:

[image]simple

And a simple, dark, slightly blue-tinted glossy material, (roughness around 0.1).

resulting in this kind of response to peak light-sources in an HDR environment.

[image]

These are the nodes: I'm not knowledgeable enough in this area to justify them -  I've a feeling changing Anisotropic Rotation is equivalent to  rotating tangent space, bar some mapping, but how it's done in the Principled shader is something I have to look up.

[image]

Comment: It looks very close! Could you please show me your nodes?

Comment: @Aotuhm.. done. The HDR lighting is a  interior with some point ceiling lights, like your the ones on your photo.

Comment: Thank you! This is very close, and I like the look.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to add some "waves" to the direction of your reflections.

So probably you should intervene on the *Normals* of your model or, more easily, your shader. Actually, since it's the *Anisotropic* reflections we need to tweak, then the *Tangent* socket is more adequate (it will basically only affect the anisotropy).

This is an unorthodox use of the *Normal Map* node but it helps somehow:

[image]

[image]

Note: my box is already a bit wawy before playing with the normals, because it has some non planar geometry near the middle due to poor topology used for a hole: this already helps on its own:

[image]

Probably there's something better than just a random noise applied to the Tangents, but I think that's the socket you should focus on to do the trick.

[image] (add your own hdri)

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll follow this approach. Yes, the non planar geometry helps in this kind of situations (radial reflections), I've seen it in the fingerprint scanner of some phones. And your use of blue lights, I didn't think about it. Thanks again